# Excel OLE DB connection refresh issues

Tags: vba, excel, oledb

I have an Excel workbook with two dynamic OLE DB queries. I'm having issues with refreshes.

To set things up I have a SQL table-valued function as the source. The data is of the nature of...

```
SGrp   SG_Desc   SKU   SKU_Desc   Server   Billed
1      Item 1    111   whatever    15        12
1      Item 2    222   some more   10         9
2      Item 3    333   zzz         10         8
3      Item 4    555   abc         20        18
```

On the first sheet ("Overall") I have a data connection that summarizes the groups with the command text of dynamically modified with one button.

```
SELECT SGrp, SG_Desc, SUM(Served) AS Served, SUM(Billed) AS Billed FROM mySQLdb ('8/19/2018','8/25/2018') WHERE SGrp <> '' GROUP BY SGrp, SG_Desc ORDER BY SG_Desc
```

I then have a cell with a data validation list that selects the group and a button to execute the VBA to dynamically modify the other connection. There's also two cells with the report start & end date for filtering. When I push the "Detail" button it runs the code below.

```
Private Sub RunDetail_Click()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim SGrp As String

Range("A1").Value = Range("G8").Value2

StartDate = Sheets("Overall").Range("H1").Value
EndDate = Sheets("Overall").Range("H2").Value
SGrp = Sheets("Overall").Range("A1").Value

SGrp = LTrim(RTrim(SGrp))

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CJP_DeliveryRecap_Detail").OLEDBConnection
    .CommandText = "SELECT SKU, SKU_Desc, Served, Billed FROM mySQLdb ('" & StartDate & "','" & EndDate & "') WHERE SG_Desc='" & SGrp & "'"
'    .Refresh
'    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CJP_DeliveryRecap_Detail").Refresh
End With

'RefreshOLEDB
'ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CJP_DeliveryRecap_Detail").Refresh
'Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

Dim rc As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Worksheets("Detail").Activate

With Worksheets("Detail").Range("CJP_DeliveryRecap_Detail")
    rc = .Rows.Count
End With

With Worksheets("Detail").Range("E1048576")
    .Select
    .End(xlUp).Select
End With
i = Selection.Row

Worksheets("Detail").Range("E5").Select

Worksheets("Detail").Range("E5:G" & i).ClearContents

Worksheets("Detail").Range("E5").Value = 1
Worksheets("Detail").Range("F5").Value = "=+CJP_DeliveryRecap_Detail[@Served]*E5"
Worksheets("Detail").Range("G5").Value = "=+CJP_DeliveryRecap_Detail[@Billed]*E5"
Sheets("Detail").Range("E5:G5").Copy Sheets("Detail").Range("E6:E" & rc + 4)
Sheets("Detail").Range("F1").Value = ("=SUM(F5:F" & rc + 4 & ")")
Sheets("Detail").Range("G1").Value = ("=SUM(G5:G" & rc + 4 & ")")

End Sub
```

So, what is it doing? The first "strange" thing is I occasionally get errors in the code that I have to continue on. A lot of times, but not all, it hits the Application.Wait line, then the Worksheets("Detail").Activate line, and sometimes the line where I set values or copy data.

There are some comments where I've been testing various refreshes etc. The issue is because while when the code completes it displays the data conn detail correctly but the calculations as to the size of the results is from the prior set. If I click the button a second time then it calculates them correctly. I would of course prefer not to have a arbitrary 3sec delay but simply run the rest of the code after the resultant records have been retrieved.

Where am I going wrong as I've been banging my head against the wall with this. Most of what I do is in Access but Excel was the proper tool in this case.

I just thought of, but not thrilled to, would it work to have a separate sub to handle the record size calcs and cell values clear\set and call that from the button click or would that still not be generated until after the original sub ends.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait till query is complete before proceeding with calculations. 
 
What you need is to add `.BackgroundQuery = False` to your connection before `.refresh`

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CJP_DeliveryRecap_Detail").OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = "SELECT SKU, SKU_Desc, Served, Billed FROM mySQLdb ......"
    .Refresh
End With
```

This should help

Comment: I had tried setting the connection itself to turn off background refresh. Tried BackgroundQuery=False before the .Refresh in the VBA. Both failed. Placing it above the .CommandText however seems to work. The problem now is when I select a new item it throws a debug at the End With for some reason and sometimes on one or more of the last three copy\value lines and even the End Sub. Not every time but it's the exception when it doesn't.

Comment: Sphinx, I have created a new spreadsheet. Created new buttons, data sources, copied and pasted the VBA code. The only thing that I changed is switching from OLEDBConnection to an ODBCConnection (Excel calls it out as "Database Query"). Interestingly the OLEDB connection seems faster but even if I enable the BackgroundQuery it now works correctly although I will disable it as the screen refreshes are annoying. I don't need it in code, just disable in the connection properties. Something must have gotten corrupt in the original book. I might try OLE DB again but... Thanks, will mark

Answer (score -1):

If the stored procedure being called from Excel does not contain "SET NOCOUNT ON" it will not run properly from Excel. I had the same issue and SET NOCOUNT ON was not included in my stored proc; the second i added it, it worked!